# Joins in MySQL are not working

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner in MySQL and trying to create a join query in MySQL.

My first SQL query is as below which displays the 2 columns votes and post

```
SELECT votes, post 
FROM `wp_votes` where votes!=''
GROUP BY votes,post asc LIMIT 0 , 30
```

**Second table is where the posts are **

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_posts`
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

What i wanna do is create a join so that it display all records from wp_posts table WHERE wp_post.ID=wp_votes.post, Also have to check if wp_votes.votes!=''

I tried the following but i am stuck on it

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts join wp_votes ON wp_posts.ID =wp_votes.post
```

Table Structure below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_title` text NOT NULL,
  `post_excerpt` text NOT NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'publish',
  `comment_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'open',
  `ping_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'open',
  `post_password` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `post_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `to_ping` text NOT NULL,
  `pinged` text NOT NULL,
  `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content_filtered` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `guid` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `post_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'post',
  `post_mime_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
  KEY `post_name` (`post_name`),
  KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
  KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
  KEY `post_author` (`post_author`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4570 ;

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_votes`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_votes` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `post` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `votes` text NOT NULL,
  `guests` text NOT NULL,
  `usersinks` text NOT NULL,
  `guestsinks` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1052 ;
```

Comment: you need to post table structure.

Comment: cant you just add Where condition to your existing query?

Comment: @Ghigo i added the table structure

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.votes, a.post, 
        b.*
FROM    wp_votes a
        INNER JOIN wp_Post b
            ON a.post = b.ID
WHERE   a.votes <> ''
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)